# Avoiding explicit type annotation for a struct constructor, where the struct contains a generic field

Tags: generics, rust, ownership

I am trying to create a struct that contains something that implements a trait which can be either an owned type or a ref-counted pointer such as `Arc`, `Rc`, etc. So far I have implemented the following using the `Borrow` trait, however, the compiler is forcing me to annotate the types of the instances returned by the `new` function, which is not ideal for the users of my crate.

How can I modify the following code, so that the user does not need to annotate the types of the instances returned by the `new` function?

```rust
struct Foo<B, T> {
    borrow: B,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}

impl<B, T> Foo<B, T> {
    fn new(borrow: B) -> Self {
        Self {
            borrow,
            _marker: Default::default()
        }
    }
}

impl <B, T> Foo<B, T> where
    B: std::borrow::Borrow<T>,
    T: std::fmt::Display {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.borrow.borrow())
    }
}

fn main() {
    // owned string (remove type annotation for error)
    let f: Foo<_, String> =
        Foo::new(String::from("hello"));
    f.print();

    // string slice (remove type annotation for error)
    let f: Foo<_, &str> =
        Foo::new("hello");
    f.print();

    // string in Arc (remove type annotation for error)
    let f: Foo<_, std::sync::Arc<String>> =
        Foo::new(std::sync::Arc::new(String::from("hello")));
    f.print();
}
```

Comment: If you are willing to swap the `Borrow` constraint for a `Deref`, then the solution is quite easy: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2bc8fe3a3c304362be360347e7fda4f). It could even be argued that `Deref` is more appropriate here...

Comment: What is the purpose of separate `B` and `T` params?

Comment: @rodrigo somehow I was under the impression that `Deref` would not work for owned values, but perhaps I was getting confused with `AsRef`. If you want to copy your comment + playground code into an answer, I will accept that solution.

Comment: @mallwright: Posted, I'm not sure if that is what you want, but I got a bit carried away with the examples...

Comment: @rodrigo the extract examples are really appreciated! `String` and `Display` are indeed placeholders for other types and the trait that `Display` represents comes from another crate making it awkward/impossible to implement for `Arc`, `Rc` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that a type, your `B` can implement `Borrow<T>` for many different `T` types, so if you don't specify the `T` somehow, the call will be ambiguous. The same is true for `AsRef`.

But it is not for `Deref`. That can only be implemented once per type, and it is already implemented for any `std` smart pointer.

The code is straightforward, because you can constrain the `Deref::Target` type:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

impl<B> Foo<B>
where
    B: Deref,
    <B as Deref>::Target: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.obj.deref());
    }
}
```

This has the drawback that will only work for smart-pointer-like types. That is if for example `B = i32` it will not work because a plain type such as `i32` doesn't implement `Deref`:

```
    let f: Foo<_> = Foo::new(42);
    f.print();

> error[E0599]: the method `print` exists for struct `Foo<{integer}>`, but its > trait bounds were not satisfied
> note: trait bound `{integer}: Deref` was not satisfied
> where
>      B: Deref,
>         ^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
```

If that is ok for you, you can stop reading here.

If that is not ok, I think the best option is to forget the `AsRef/Deref/Borrow` thing and just require that `B` implements either the trait you want, or a facade for that trait.

The details would vary depending on exactly what you want to implement. If your trait is actually `Display` and that is not a placeholder, then you don't actually need anything special, because `Display` is implemented for `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>`, `Arc<T>`, etc. when `T: Display`. So you just write:

```
impl<B> Foo<B>
where B: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.borrow)
    }
}
```

But I'm guessing that your actual trait is not `Display`. Again the details vary depending on whether you own that trait or not. Imagine this trait:

```
trait Printable {
    fn print(&self);
}
impl Printable for str {
    fn print(&self) { println!("s:{}", self); }
}
impl Printable for i32 {
    fn print(&self) { println!("i:{}", self); }
}
```

If it is yours you can write the following code directly, but if it is third-party you will need a *facade* trait:

```
trait AsPrintable {
    type Target: Printable + ?Sized;
    fn as_printable(&self) -> &Self::Target;
}
```

And your `Foo` would be:

```
impl<B> Foo<B>
where
    B: AsPrintable,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        self.obj.as_printable().print();
    }
}
```

Then you can implement the trait for any types you want. The small inconvenient here is that you would like two write two blanket implementations:

```
impl<T: Printable> AsPrintable for T {
    type Target = T;
    fn as_printable(&self) -> &T { self }
}
impl<T: Deref> AsPrintable for T
    where <T as Deref>::Target: AsPrintable
{
    type Target = <<T as Deref>::Target as AsPrintable>::Target;
    fn as_printable(&self) -> &Self::Target { self.deref().as_display() }
}
```

But only one or the other is allowed, Rustc will not allow both because of ambiguity. If needed, this can be fixed with a few manual implementations for the needed wrappers. Or a new-type to replace the first blanket impl, such as this one:

```
struct MakePrintable<T>(T);

impl<T: Printable> AsPrintable for MakePrintable<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn as_printable(&self) -> &T { &self.0 }
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=29111a8be1e1b055b76901bf33b7d085) with the whole example.

Comment: For my particular use case, the trait in question is provided by the user but is augmented by a macro that I control, hence I think the best solution is to copy what is done in the standard library with the `Display` trait and to just add blanket implementations for `Arc`, `Rc`, `Box` etc.

Comment: Note that a (small) drawback of this approach is that you can't have `Box<T>` (and friends) as owned types.